# string or nsstring with string

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

Lets assume myProp is @property (retain) NSString * myProp and synthesized for us....

```
self.myProp = @"some value";//string literal?

self.myProp = [NSString stringWithString:@"some value"];
```

Is there a difference here? 
Is the first one a string literal that doesnt get autoreleased or is it just in memory for it's current scope and I dont have to worry about it?

Comment: Up-voted since this hangs a lot of people up.

Comment: Just use string literals if you're unsure, they are _almost_ always the right choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to spend some time with the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html). From the linked section (about creating `@"string constants"`):

> Such an object is created at compile
>   time and exists throughout your
>   program’s execution. The compiler
>   makes such object constants unique on
>   a per-module basis, and they’re never
>   deallocated, though you can retain and
>   release them as you do any other
>   object.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. Looks like I will keep using my NSString object.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal is a hard-coded NSString that exists indefinitely while your application is running. You can even send it messages that NSString responds to, such as `[@"test" length]`.

To answer your question, the first line is setting the property to the string literal, while the second is going through an extra step of creating a new string based off the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the posts by Joshua and Preston, in fact `[NSString stringWithString:xxx]` returns `xxx` itself when `xxx` is a literal.
This is an implementation detail, so you shouldn't write any program relying on this fact, but it's fun to know.

You can check this fact thus:

```
 NSString*a=@"foo";
 NSString*b=[NSString stringWithString:a];
 NSLog(@"a at %p, class %@",a,[a class]);
 NSLog(@"b at %p, class %@",b,[b class]);
```

At least on my 10.6.3 box, both give the same address, with class `NSCFString`.

Remember: `retain` & `release` concern your responsibility on the ownership, and they don't always decrease/increase the retain count. The implementation can do whatever optimization it wants, as long as the said optimization doesn't break the ownership policy.

Or in other words: write `retain` & `release` so that the objects are kept/destroyed in the case the implementation always does the naive increase/decrease of the retain count. That's the contract between Cocoa and you. But Cocoa can do and indeed does a lot of optimization.